# How to combine two ClosedRange in Swift?

Tags: swift, collections

I am learning Quick Sort in swift and need to compose a complicated array.

Here is the code:

```
var arrayOne = 1...500
var arrayTwo = 501...1000
var array_one = arrayOne.reversed()
var array_two = arrayTwo.reversed()
var array = arrayOne + arrayTwo
```

I want to combine `arrayOne + arrayTwo` to `array`.

I can not use the `+` operator, Xcode tips me

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two
>   'CountableClosedRange' operands

I know how to get it by using for loops.

Elegant way is really needed. Such as Higher order function.

Comment: FYI - `arrayOne` and `arrayTwo` are not arrays. They are closed ranges. So what do you want `array` to be? What if the two ranges are something like `1...100` and `400...500`? What should the result be?

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you are unable to  use the `+` because they are *not* arrays, they are *ranges* (`CountableClosedRange`). So, what's the expected result by combing them?

Comment: @maddy, I want collection of numbers not ordered, and easy to remember and judge. So I can focus on the Algorithm. Martin R exactly gives what I want, what a Collection Master.  And I  know `arc4random_uniform(UInt32)` to create random number. `arc4random_uniform(UInt32)` , every time I run, the raw data is different.

Comment: @Ahmad F , expecting as Martin R's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1...500` is a *range* and `(1...500).reversed()` is a *collection.* Both are sequences so that you can *append* them to an array:

```
let rangeOne = 1...500
let rangeTwo = 501...1000

let array = [] + rangeOne.reversed() + rangeTwo.reversed()

// [500, 499, ..., 2, 1, 1000, 999, ..., 502, 501]
```

Alternative solutions are:

```
let array = Array(rangeOne.reversed()) + rangeTwo.reversed()
let array = Array([rangeOne.reversed(), rangeTwo.reversed()].joined())
let array = Array(rangeOne.reversed()) + Array(rangeTwo.reversed())
let array = [rangeOne.reversed(), rangeTwo.reversed()].flatMap { $0 }
```